# preserve my downloads

Tags: usb-creator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

I use a USB drive to boot Ubuntu and when I download my preferred language it isn't kept for me to the next time I boot Ubuntu, so every time that I boot Ubuntu, I need to download my preferred language again. Is there any way to preserve my language and other applications that I downloaded at the last boot to the next time I boot Ubuntu from my USB driver?

Thanks in advance!!

atar.